# Could not run Vuforia Application from Unity on iOS. Code signature invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I spend hours to understand where is the problem, but still the same result. I have tried to run a simple Vuforia + Unity + iOS project, everything builds well but on iOS device (iPhone 13.3.1) I have the errors in Xcode terminal and application crashes:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Vuforia.framework/Vuforia
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application
  /F15D1638-5D78-432F-979D-430805041617/newchristmas.app/newchristmas

  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application
    /F15D1638-5D78-432F-979D-430805041617/newchristmas.app/Frameworks/Vuforia.framework/Vuforia: 
  code signature invalid for 
   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application
    /F15D1638-5D78-432F-979D-430805041617/newchristmas.app/Frameworks/Vuforia.framework/Vuforia'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application
    /F15D1638-5D78-432F-979D-430805041617/newchristmas.app/Frameworks/Vuforia.framework/Vuforia:
    stat() failed with errno=25
```

I have already tried to reinstall Xcode and Unity, but the same problem.

On Unity, I have added Vuforia Licence Key in Vuforia Configuration.
[image: Vuforia Configuration]

And here my Unity Player Settings
[image: Unity Player Settings]

On Xcode, I have auto signing
[image: Xcode signing]

My environment:

- Xcode 11.3.1 (Personal Team)
- Unity 2018.4.17f1 (tried different versions). The application runs without problems in Unity Game Mode.
- Vuforia 8.3.8

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have bought an Apple Developer Membership, sign my app with new (paid) signature and error has gone.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did your previous account expired? I'm trying to decide whether renewing the membership or creating a new one.

Comment: No, my previous account didn't expire yet.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the signing setting not being right for the Vuforia frameworks that are embedded in the app.
Check what your settings are in this screen in XCode, the ones in the green box:

[image: XCode General settings]

This is from a working project with Unity 2018.4.16 and Vuforia 8.3.8, in XCode 11.3.1, so pretty similar to yours.

Comment: I already have checked these settings, but the problem still exists.